# Twitter bootstrap padding issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, padding

I can't figure out why my navigation at the bottom of this page ("prev" and "next" links) are longer than my #bloglist post teaser that are above width wise. I'm using twitter bootstrap out of the box and am using the scaffolding that they offer.

http://www.b-lew.me/page/3/

any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: One problem which probably has nothing to with your problem is that you have same id on multiple divs but obviously an id should be unique

Comment: Okay I went through and fixed that, good suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some markup inconsistencies :

- Each of your rows should be a `.row` containing a `.span12` (and you won't need your `.margin-left` class)
- Almost everything is floating, and `float: left` elements will not fill their container to their right
- `clear: both` is not needed, just use the `.clearfix` class for the container, but you usually won't need it

Here is the markup I tried :

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="well bloglist clearfix">
                <!-- etc -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And for the css

`.bloglist` should not be floating left.

It appears that there is a lot of residual markup from another design, and IMHO you are going to have a lot more graphic bugs if you don't stick to the proper bootstrap architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the help @sherbrow! Things are looking much better now! I really appreciate you taking the time to help me sort that out! It seams as though when I have a span of 4 and then 8 my span8 column is jumping down for some reason.

Comment: @b-lew This is caused by the well having paddings and borders. Here is an example with fluid or tweaking : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/DCXya/). I would strongly suggest the first one, using `.row-fluid` in the `<!-- etc -->` zone, and then spans.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are expecting the overall size to be span12, evidenced by `</div><!-- /span12 -->` However! You do not have this class declared in the opening block anywhere, and your bloglist items are span4 and span7, so the overall size would be span11. I edited a bloglist item to be span4/8, which seemed to align with the pager. I would revist your opening markup to get it to the expected size

Comment: Also, I've never before tried to answer a question on a site that changed every time I reloaded it :)

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to fix my problem. Thanks for taking a look. I'm working on the markup right  now.